# Keyboard problem, related to SDL

Tags: keyboard, sdl

I'm having a problem with my keyboard and SDL (and some other things too).

Basically, whenever I press a key in say the pong clone I made (or anything using SDL really), that key is either registered as being pressed twice or if the key is held, then it kind of just skips (on and off again). This happens in some games I have too (presumably games that also use SDL for input).

This problem does not appear on Windows using the same applications (ran Windows in a VM just to try it out) and also didn't appear in a previous install of Ubuntu.

So my question is: how do I reinstall the input driver in Ubuntu (or anything related to it) without reinstalling the entire OS.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a bug in libsdl 2.0.5. It is supposed to be fixed at head, but Ubuntu still uses the bad version.

- https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/repeat-flag-on-sdl-keyboardevent-not-being-set-on-2-0-5/21978
- https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3472
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056515/sdl2-key-repeat-not-working

Comment: Thanks for the info, a reinstall of Ubuntu (still 16.04) has fixed the issue and everything works now.